# TreeView Binding to an xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

XML:

```
<Parent Name="Jodi">
<Children Name="xxx" age="20">
<Children Name="zzz" age="21">
</Parent>

<Parent Name="John">
<Children Name="aaa" age="18">
<Children Name="bbb" age="17">
</Parent>
```

I am trying to bind the above xml file to a TreeView on my asp.net page;

ASP.Net:

```
  <asp:XmlDataSource ID="DataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="C:/Parents.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
<asp:TreeView ID="tvParents" runat="server">
<DataBindings>
<asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Parent" TextField="#InnerText" />
<asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Children" TextField="#InnerText" />
</DataBindings>
</asp:TreeView>
```

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tvParents.DataBind();
    }
```

I am trying to bind to the tree view like:

```
Jodi
  XXX
  ZZZ
John
  aaa
  bbb
```

My tree view is not displayed on the page ,Can any one have a look and guide me ?

Comment: in your xml child tag is Children and in your treeview databindings you have mention DataMember="Child". Is this not wrong ?

Comment: @WaqarJanjua: That's a typo ,just updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must Add DataSourceId attributes on Treeview

```
 <asp:XmlDataSource ID="DataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="C:/Parents.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
<asp:TreeView ID="tvParents" runat="server" DataSourceId ="DataSource1">
   <DataBindings>
     <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Parent" TextField="#InnerText" />
     <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Child" TextField="#InnerText" />
   </DataBindings>
</asp:TreeView>
```

Comment: I did that.But I am able to see the elements not values of the elements

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your IIS has no access to "C:/Parents.xml". You might be better of using Server.MapPath() and placing the file where the ASPX page runs.

Comment: :My IIS has access to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I came across something similar today - have you tried pointing the value field of the child at the attribute?

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="DataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="C:/Parents.xml">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
<asp:TreeView ID="tvParents" runat="server">
<DataBindings>
<asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Parent" TextField="#InnerText" />
<asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Children" ValueField="Name" TextField="#InnerText" />
</DataBindings>
</asp:TreeView>
```